# Custom event rule not firing in Adobe DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

I'm using DTM to listen for an event-based rule, named "My Custom Rule". The event type is "custom", as I'm using custom events to track actions from a 3rd party widget. This is my configuration below. It's fairly bland, and I have no conditions (yet). The custom event name is "my-widget-loaded".

[image: DTM Manager]

Within my 3rd party widget, I trigger my custom event:

`document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-widget-loaded'));`

In the console, I see:

> SATELLITE: detected my-widget-loaded on #documentument

But it never fires my rule, I never see a message like:

> SATELLITE: Rule "My Custom Rule" fired.

I have verified that I can create custom event handlers within the console and they fire just fine.

What can I do to make my rule fire? Why isn't it working?

Comment: "my-widget-loaded" vs "wtb-load", you sure you have the right event name?

Comment: @BrettAHale that was a typo, fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTM (and Launch) does not properly listen for custom events when using `document` as the **Element or Tag Selector**. Use `body` (and `document.body.dispatchEvent`) instead.

Comment: This is correct. Changing to `body` worked. Is there any documentation for this? This would have saved some time. Additionally, I had to check the box `Apply event handler directly to element`.

Comment: Not that I know of. I just found out from dealing with similar issue and poked at the DTM library to see what it did.

Comment: That's impressive! I was digging in their minified code and wasn't getting anywhere.